# PowerApps, Update ThisItem value based on click of button

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, powerapp, powerapps-forms, powerapps-canvas

I have the following in my browsescreen1.

[image]

[image]

This is already populated "NOT Started" in my SharePoint list, it is the default value i have inputted manually for every record.

Now on my EditForm I have a save button:

OnSelect:
`UpdateContext({VarProgress:"In Progress"});SubmitForm(EditForm1_1);`

How can I update my NOT Started to In Progress when clicking save?

Comment: Is "Attestation Status" column editable field in Power apps form? Try setting Default property of control to `VarProgress`. Let me know if this works.

Comment: Attestation status is just text i inputted, its not a field. "Status" is an actual field in my sharepoint, but i do not have the card in  my app

Comment: Try suggestions given in my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using formula like below in `OnSuccess` property of `EditForm1_1` control:

```
Patch(
    SPListDataSourceName,
    EditForm1_1.LastSubmit.ID,
    {
        Status: VarProgress
    }
)
```

---

**Or** use formula like below in `OnSelect` property of Save button control:

```
Patch(
    SPListDataSourceName, 
    ThisItem,
    EditForm1_1.Updates,
    {Status: "In Progress"}
)
```

Comment: getting an error here :

Patch(
    [testme], 
    ThisItem.Status,
    EditForm1_1.Updates,
    {ThisItem.Status: "In Progress"}
)

How cna i fix this?

Comment: 2nd parameter to patch function is the context of item you want to update in SharePoint list. Use `ThisItem` instead of `ThisItem.Status`. Refer formula given in my answer. You just need to change the name of list in that formula.

Comment: Im getting `This Name isnt recognized`  and specifcied column `Status` does not exist.

Comment: Can you try using first solution in my answer? Note: You have to use the correct name of your Status column.